# Bootstrap Validation Error Messages CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using [Bootstrap 3 Popover Validation With JQuery](http://mingliangfeng.me/github%20project/2013/08/08/jquery-validate-bootstrap-popover-demo/) . I am facing the issue of the css. I have textboxes in table. Validation is working fine the only issue is that unable to show error above the respective textbox.

[image: Validation Picture].

The error in the above picture should points to the right textbox which i have highlighted but its not happening this way. CSS I used for coloring is:

CSS

```
.popover.error-popover {
    background-color: #F2DEDE;
    border-color: #EED3D7;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #B94A48;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: none;
    z-index: 1099;
}
</style>
```

JS code is:

```
$('#myform').validate_popover({onsubmit: false, popoverPosition: 'top'});
```

HTML
The width of each textbox is 55. here is a structure of the above table.

```
<form id="myform">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input style="width:55px" name="code" />
</td>
<td>
<input style="width:55px" id="type" name="type"/>
</td>
.
.
.
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you provide an online demo on JSFiddle or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup css definition for the arrow too:

```
.popover.error-popover.top .arrow {
    border-top-color: #EED3D7;
    left: 30px;
}
```

Play around with colors (style.css) [in this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A3LOPDlWsyCXCaJtpZsw?p=preview)